# Delete rows that don't have a reference anymore

Tags: sql, subquery, sql-delete

I want to delete all rows of the seconde table that don't have a reference to the first one anymore or are 'NULL'. And that in a single query if possible.

[image: Visual Representation]

I thought of an outer join but that didn't work since I got the missing rows of both tables. I can't do it in code either because the 'IN' query would become to big for Oracle and I can't just loop through because that would take too long. That's why I was hoping that it could be done with a single query?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  The query you tried would also be insightful.  What does a "reference" mean in your question?

Answer (score 0):

In most databases, `not exists` is a supported solution:

```
delete from table2
where ref is null or not exists (
    select 1
    from table1
    where table1.id = table2.ref
)
```

Note that this would be much simpler solved by setting up a proper foreign key between child table/column `table2(re)` and parent `table1(id)`: foreign keys come with useful features such as `on delete cascade`, that perform such operation for you under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Delete Statement:

```
DELETE FROM Table2 LEFT JOIN Table1 ON ref=id WHERE Table1.id IS NULL
```